# How can I extract a text from a bytes file using python

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to code a script that gets the code of a website, saves all html in a file and after that extracts some information.

For the moment I´ve done the first part, I've saved all html into a text file.

Now I have to extract the relevant information and then save it in another text file.

But I'm having problems with encoding and also I don´t know very well how to extract the text in python.

Parsing a website:

```
import urllib.request
```

file name to store the data

```
file_name = r'D:\scripts\datos.txt'
```

I want to get the text that goes after this tag `<p class="item-description">`  and before this other one `</p>`

```
tag_starts_with = '<p class="item-description">'
tag_ends_with = '</p>'
```

I get the website code and I save it into a text file

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.website.com/") as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    data = response.read() 
    out_file.write(data)
```

`print (out_file)`   # First question how can I print the file? Gives me an error, I can´t print bytes

the file is now full of html text so I want to open it and process it

```
file_for_results = open(r'D:\scripts\datos.txt',encoding="utf8")
```

Extract information from the file

second question how to do a substring of the lines that contain the file and get the text between `p class="item-description"` and
`/p` so i can store in file_for_results

Here is the pseudocode that I'm not capable to code.

```
for line in file_to_filter:
    if line contains word_starts_with
      copy in file_for_results until you find </p>
```

Comment: For a start, your back-slashes in the filenames are an issue, use a raw string, e.g.: `r'D:\scripts\datos.txt'`

Comment: Have a look at a library dedicated specifically to parsing HTML and giving you access to the parts you want: [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this is an assignment of some sort, where you need to parse the html given an algorithm, if not just use Beautiful Soup.

The pseudocode actually translates to python code quite easily:

```
file_to_filter = open("file.html", 'r')
out_file = open("text_output",'w')
for line in file_to_filter:
    if word_starts_with in line:
        print(line, end='', file=out_file) # Store data in another file
    if word_ends_with in line:
        break
```

And of course you need to close the files, make sure you remove the tags and so on, but this is roughly what your code should be given this algorithm.